# How to get all Data Objects related to Asset in Pimcore?

Tags: pimcore

I need to get all Data Objects related to Asset.
I can't find it in Asset API documentation: https://pimcore.com/docs/pimcore/current/Development_Documentation/Assets/Working_with_PHP_API.html

How to do it the most efficient way?

Answer (score 0):

You can see and debug how it is used in Pimcore Admin Panel on 'Requires' Tab of Asset:

```
$dependencies = $asset->getDependencies()->getRequiredBy();
foreach ($dependencies as $dependency) {
    if ($dependency['type'] !== 'object') {
        continue;
    }
    $concreteDataObject = Concrete::getById($dependency['id']);
}
```